# Error executing rhc setup - An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!doctype "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift, openshift-client-tools

After Executing `> rhc setup` and then entering my hostname i always get this error message

[image]

Steps that i've done:

1- installed Ruby 1.9.3

2- installed rhc using gem `gem install rhc`

3- Executed `> rhc setup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is some kind of bug.

But, there is another way to manually generate SSH public-private key pairs and upload them to OpenShift

**1- Generate new SSH keys**

```
C:\> ssh-keygen
```

It will ask you where to save the key files just press "Enter" -> this will generate key-pairs with name "id_rsa" in "C:\Users\YOU\.ssh"
also Press Enter when asked for passphrase to keep it empty

**2- Upload you Public Key to OpenShift**

```
C:/>rhc sshkey add id_rsa C:\Users\YOU\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

It will then ask you for your credentials on OpenShift, once done your public key is now uploaded to OpenShift

**3- Configuring SSH to use the Generated private key when connecting to your APP**

a- Make sure you have an environment variable "HOME" pointing to "C:/Users/YOU/.ssh", if not create one

b- open "C:/Users/YOU/.ssh/" if you find config file open it , if not create one by running the following command:

```
touch config
```

Now add the following lines to config file:

```
Host ChooseAName
 HostName APPName-NameSpace.rhcloud.com
 IdentityFile ~\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
```

save and close

**4- Now Connecting to your App:**

First, Get the command that enables you to connect remotely to your app on rhcloud server , you can get it using the OpenShift web console

[image]

enter that to you command line and you will be connected trough a secure shell to you APP on rhcloud

Comment: 'ssh-keygen' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was typing

```
rhc setup --server=my_app_domain
```

but in fact, the relevant server was the Openshift Enterprise server that was hosting my domain. When I used this server, it worked fine.