# Rhc setup ruby errors and invalid character at <!doctype

Tags: ruby, openshift

When running rhc setup I get multiple errors from Ruby and after that I get tons of same error from ruby again leading into `An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!doctype "`.

```
C:\Users\Micu>rhc setup -l myemail@example.com
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::NIL is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Data is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::TRUE is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::FALSE is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/commander-4.2.1/lib/commander/user_interaction.rb:328: warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated
OpenShift Client Tools (RHC) Setup Wizard

This wizard will help you upload your SSH keys, set your application namespace, and check that other programs like Git
are properly installed.

If you have your own OpenShift server, you can specify it now. Just hit enter to use the server for OpenShift Online:
openshift.redhat.com.
Enter the server hostname: |openshift.redhat.com|
```

That includes the first errors on the top and after I hit enter on this part:

```
You can add more servers later using 'rhc server'.

Using myemail@example.com to login to openshift.redhat.com
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:616: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:872: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:746: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:616: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:872: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/httpclient-2.6.0.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:950: warning: Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
An unexpected error occurred: invalid character at "<!doctype "
```

I get this.
I have everything up to date and have restarted computer many times. Also tried the instructions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34990538/12299427). Is there a bug or am I doing something wrong (possibly doing something wrong because I am completely new on this subject)?

Comment: Your versions are WAYYYY out of date. Your commander version is 6 years old, for example. Chances are you either need a much older version of Ruby or a much newer version of your app (and its libraries).

Comment: `rhc` is for OpenShift 2, which has been out of support since 2016, so this is no longer maintained